# Development to production existing profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl-certificate

I have developed an application which supports `GCM` push notifications through `APN`, but the certificates are created in development environment now i need to upload that app to the App Store.

What should I do now:

1. So can i directly edit and upload the new `CSR`
2. Or should i follow the whole new process by creating new app id to upload the app to App Store.
3. Or in some other way?

What way should I follow.

Comment: Edit your app ID and create new certificate for push notification with production.

Comment: there is no need to create new app id and all

Comment: okay, when i edit the already uploaded development certificate is there so should if revoke it or not ?

Comment: You don't need to revoke or edit development certificates. just create new Ad Hoc Certificates and use them to upload your app.

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla, Ad Hoc cretificate ?

Comment: Ad Hoc certificates are distribution/production certificates used for distribution of app or to upload on app store.

You will also need to generate App Store provisionaning profile.

Comment: You will find another field below your development certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit existing App ID and use same CSR you used for development.

Here is the link you can review for enabling push notification for production environment.

https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808718-iOS-Creating-a-Push-Notification-Certificate

For App Store submission, you need to create App Store profile.

Comment: how do i know the same csr i uploaded that time, i lost in case ?